# Highlight Nav item when using anchor scrolling

Tags: anchor, highlight

I'm pretty new when it comes to jQuery so I need someone with a little more experience to help me out. I have a Nav with 3 items - Work About Contact

By default I have work selected but I would like it to change the active class to which ever is clicked. I have anchor scrolling working but I would like to have it highlight to the correct nav item when clicked. Also if it is possible when scrolling down the page and getting to the next section for it to change highlight automatically.

This is the jQuery I am using for the anchor scrolling.

```
    <script>$(function() {
    var main-nav = $("#main-nav"), pos = main-nav.offset();
    $(window).scroll(function() { 
        if($(this).scrollTop() > (pos.top + 10) && $(this).scrollTop() < 15000 && main-nav.css('position') == 'static') { main-nav.addClass('fixed');  } 
        else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top && main-nav.hasClass('fixed')){ main-nav.removeClass('fixed'); }
        else if($(this).scrollTop() > 15000 && main-nav.hasClass('fixed')){ main-nav.removeClass('fixed'); }
        })
    });
    </script>
    <script>$(function() {
            $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
                var $anchor = $(this);

                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
                /*
                if you don't want to use the easing effects:
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                }, 1000);
                */
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the CSS

```
    #main-nav{
      font: bold 12px 'Bitter', serif;
      width: 145px;
      float: right;
    }
    #main-nav li{
      float: left;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 10px 2px 0 2px;
      color: #c4c5c5;
    }
    #main-nav li:last-child{
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    #main-nav a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #c4c5c5;
    }
    #main-nav a:hover{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #919292;
    }
    #main-nav a.active{
      color: #919292;
    }
```

Here is the HTML

```
    <div id="main-nav" class="">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a class="active" href="#work">Work</a></li>
                    <li>/</li>
                    <li><a href="#anchor-about">About</a></li>
                    <li>/</li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

If someone could help me out I would really really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `active` class to specify which anchor should be highlighted, you just need to make sure that the correct anchor has that class.  Fixing that when the nav items are clicked is straightforward, in your `$('ul.nav a').bind` add:

```
  $('ul.nav a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
```

[Here is a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ezalib/2/edit).

To highlight the nav's as the page is scrolled you would just compare the scrollTop for the page with the offsets of elements in the DOM...similar to your current code in `$(window).scroll`.